# QuickSearch JQuery for only certain columns

Tags: jquery, gridview, asp.net-mvc-5

I started [JQuery and the "quicksearch" script](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Column-Wise-Search-and-Filter-in-WebGrid-using-TextBox-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) which allowed me to  create a "textbox" search field at the first row of each column.  [image: Jquery + SearchString]

My Goal (edited based on responses):
I want to modify this to not have a text box above the "Active" column as well as a few others not pictured.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/quicksearch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //Add Header Row with TextBoxes.
        var row = $("<TR />");
        $("#WebGrid TR").eq(0).find("TH").each(function () {
            row.append("<th><input type = 'text' /></th>");
        });
        $("#WebGrid TR").eq(0).after(row);

        //Applying the QuickSearch Plugin to each TextBox.

        $("#WebGrid TR").eq(1).find("INPUT").each(function (i) {
            $(this).quicksearch("#WebGrid tr:not(:has(th))", {
                'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {

                     return $(row).children(":eq(" + i + ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0].toLowerCase()) != -1; 
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

New Script which hides the textboxes for fields I do not want to search, but the search is off by number of columns skipped:

New Script:

```
$("#WebGrid TR").eq(0).find("TH").each(function (i) {
            if ((i == 0) || (i == 5) || (i == 7) || (i == 10))
                row.append("<th>&nbsp;</th>");
            else
            row.append("<th><input type = 'text' /></th>");
        });
```

New View:
   [image: Off by blank column count]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `index` argument of `$.each` and an array of exclude indices to determine whether to append an input or not

```
    var noInput = [0,4,7];// example values

    $("#WebGrid TR").eq(0).find("TH").each(function (i) {
        var $th=$('<th>');
        if(!noInput.includes(i)){
           $th.append('<input type="text" />')
        }
        row.append($th);
    });
```

You could also modify and use the `<th>` text values in array and look for `$(this).text()` within the loop

Comment: Based on your suggestion, i made the following mod which gives me the correct text boxes, but the search is off by one or more columns... 
    var row = $("<TR />");
            $("#WebGrid TR").eq(0).find("TH").each(function (i) {
                if ((i == 0) || (i == 5) || (i == 7) || (i == 10))
                    row.append("<th>&nbsp;</th>");
                else
                row.append("<th><input type = 'text' /></th>");
            });
            $("#WebGrid TR").eq(0).after(row); I will append this to the original question

Comment: You will need to loop over the `<th>` again not the `<th>input` to implement the event listener. Then use the `<th>` index again for the column search. Or get the parent `<th>` index()` to match columns

Comment: Sorry you lost me at the 3rd `<th>` Would you please modify your response?!

Comment: `$("#WebGrid TR").eq(1).find("INPUT").each(function () { var i = $(this).parent().index(); $(this).quicksearch....`

Comment: I figured out another way to do this that is cleaner and more efficient,but I would love to see your solution if you're willing to enter it as an answer (just for my own education/edification!) Thanks in advance!